# Insufficient contextual information to determine type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++03

I've done research and I can't make sense of this message at all. Everything I find seems to be a bug with the compiler itself. I've also read somewhere *'insufficient contextual information to determine type' is not a helpful message*.
**My question: Does anyone have information on what this compile error message means?**
I understand this question might be code specific. My code merely declares a global anonymous struct, and then once it tries to access it in a function I get this error (or so I've evaluated it).
EDIT: I got my code to compile! - But I still don't know what the error means, so I'll leave the question open.
EDIT: Here's my code, as far as I'd suppose is important:

```
    typedef ofstream::pos_type ofilepos;
    struct stack  // stack is my own stack data-structure
    {
      // ...
      // int L; struct N *l;
      stack(): L(0), l(NULL) {}
    }

    // ...

    struct
    {
      const char* zero;
      stack<ofilepos> chunks; // it was 'chunks();' with (), and it didn't work
    } _fileext = {"\0\0\0"};

    // ...

    ofstream& write_stack_pushsize(ofstream& f)
    {
      _fileext.chunks.push(new ofilepos(f.tellp()));
      f.write(_fileext.zero,4);
      return f;
    }
```

I think it might have been because I was calling a constructor in a struct declaration, rather than later... or something... it could be a bug in C++03.

Comment: Can you post the actual code instead of describe it?

Comment: What is an `ofilepos`? Could you give us a minimal *complete* example?

Comment: why you are returning `f` which already is a variable captured by reference ?

Comment: @user1849534: It's likely so that function calls can be chained together, much like chaining `operator <<` (though I'll admit this usage here is a little strange).

Comment: idk :) - I just happened to pick up that habit. It does allow me to do stuff like f.write_byte(6).write_byte(5).write_byte(4)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding this code,

```
struct
{
  const char* zero;
  stack<ofilepos> chunks();
} _fileext = {"\0\0\0"};
```

there is no way to provide a definition of the `chunks` member function after the anonymous struct definition.

Considering also the following usage example,

```
ofstream& write_stack_pushsize(ofstream& f)
{
  _fileext.chunks.push(new ofilepos(f.tellp()));
  f.write(_fileext.zero,4);
  return f;
}
```

apparently you meant to define `chunks` as a data member instead of as a function member.

By the way, using underscore at the start of a name can possibly conflict with names in the implementation of the standard library. E.g. these names are reserved in the global namespace (if I recall correctly). The usual convention is instead to have an underscore at the *end* of a name, to signify "member".

To signyfy "global" I simply use a namespace that I call `g`. :-)

Comment: Yes, I did mean it to be a data member. I wonder if the compiler thought it a function. But my code compiles :-). What does the message mean, though? I tried to give as much relevant context as I can.

Comment: @AUTO: just remove the argument list parenthesis in the declaration.